# как сделать задержку между командами telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать задержку между выполнениями команд в телеграм боте. Например что бы пользователь написал команду, а потом ещё раз и ему писало "Подождите 5 секунд перед выполнение этой команды" и так в течении 5 секунд. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень рад вашей помощи.

Comment: Хранить время сообщения и `chat_id` и проверять текущее время от сохраненного времени. Я бы сделал в базе данных, но можно и хранить в памяти, например, в словаре

Comment: а можно ответ как это делаеться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример ответа сделан в [python-telegram-bot](/questions/tagged/python-telegram-bot) (в *UPD* добавил вариант с [pytelegrambotapi](/questions/tagged/pytelegrambotapi)), но реализацию можно переписать на другие библиотеки.

Действия:

- Заводите структуру, например, словарь или базу данных для хранения id чата и времени сообщения
- Получая сообщение проверяйте разницу между текущем временем и тем, что был сохранен

  - Можно хранить текущее время в секундах, `timestamp`
  - В примере время храню в объекте `datetime`, при вычитании одного `datetime` из другого `datetime` будет получен объект `timedelta`, у которого есть метод `total_seconds`
- Если разница меньше или равна заданных секунд, то отправляем сообщение о ожидании

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8e4d03f65bff32b4ac0f35840cee7c58f7420893/telegram_bot_examples/restriction_on_frequent_sending_of_messages__using_dict.py#L30)

```
import datetime as DT

...

CHAT_BY_DATETIME = dict()

def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.effective_message

    text = 'Получено!'
    need_seconds = 50
    current_time = DT.datetime.now()
    last_datetime = CHAT_BY_DATETIME.get(message.chat_id)

    # Если первое сообщение (время не задано)
    if not last_datetime:
        CHAT_BY_DATETIME[message.chat_id] = current_time
    else:
        # Разница в секундах между текущим временем и временем последнего сообщения
        delta_seconds = (current_time - last_datetime).total_seconds()

        # Осталось ждать секунд перед отправкой
        seconds_left = int(need_seconds - delta_seconds)

        # Если время ожидания не закончилось
        if seconds_left > 0:
            text = f'Подождите {seconds_left} секунд перед выполнение этой команды'
        else:
            CHAT_BY_DATETIME[message.chat_id] = current_time

    message.reply_text(text, quote=True)

...
```

**UPD.**
[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dd43a5ba251ead34159475f7a8581857d8144444/telegram_bot__telethon__examples/restriction_on_frequent_sending_of_messages__using_dict.py#L26)

```
import datetime as DT

# SOURCE: pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
import telebot

from config import TOKEN


bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


CHAT_BY_DATETIME = dict()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def on_start(message: telebot.types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Write something')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def on_request(message: telebot.types.Message):
    text = 'Получено!'
    need_seconds = 50
    current_time = DT.datetime.now()
    last_datetime = CHAT_BY_DATETIME.get(message.chat.id)

    # Если первое сообщение (время не задано)
    if not last_datetime:
        CHAT_BY_DATETIME[message.chat.id] = current_time
    else:
        # Разница в секундах между текущим временем и временем последнего сообщения
        delta_seconds = (current_time - last_datetime).total_seconds()

        # Осталось ждать секунд перед отправкой
        seconds_left = int(need_seconds - delta_seconds)

        # Если время ожидания не закончилось
        if seconds_left > 0:
            text = f'Подождите {seconds_left} секунд перед выполнение этой команды'
        else:
            CHAT_BY_DATETIME[message.chat.id] = current_time

    bot.reply_to(message, text)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @gutamur_, пожалуйста :) Если мой ответ помог, то проголосуйте и примите его :)

Comment: @gli9red я не много не понимаю как работает python-telegram-bot,и не могу понять как заменить код на telebot, если вам не сложно, можете мне не много помочь?

Comment: @gutamur_, копируете код из ответа (нужен импорт datetime, объявление переменной с словарем, и кусок кода функции). Вместо `message = update.effective_message`, `message.chat_id` и `message.reply_text(text, quote=True)` используете аналоги `telebot`. Первое, можно убрать. Второе это `message.chat.id`. А третье, `bot.reply_to(message, text)`

Comment: ладно, сейчас попробую

Comment: @gutamur_, накидал на telebot https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dd43a5ba251ead34159475f7a8581857d8144444/telegram_bot__telethon__examples/restriction_on_frequent_sending_of_messages__using_dict.py#L26

Comment: Спасибо огромное, прям при огромное!!!!!

Comment: @gutamur_, пожалуйста :)